# When to return the data or pass in a variable to write the data to

Tags: language-agnostic

Is there a situation where it's better suited to pass in an existing List to write the data to versus returning a List that may have been instantiated inside the called method?

Comment: What are you really asking? Is this really language agnostic?

Comment: If you are performing an iterative operation, passing the existing list might improve performance over variable instantiation inside the method.

Comment: If you're using C, then passing a pointer to a list, rather than allocating something inside the function, can make it much clearer who is responsible for freeing the list.

Answer (score 0):

If your method is subject to interrupts, you may want it to modify an existing list versus returning one. Doing so, you will prevent errors that might occur because an interrupt occurred before the list was returned.